# Arflow in ECS cluster

Tags: airflow, amazon-ecs

I have previously used Airflow running Ubuntu VM. I was able to login into VM via WinSCP and putty to run commands and edit Airflow related files as required.

But i first time came across Airflow running AWS ECS cluster. I am new to ECS So, i am trying to see what is the best possible way to :

- run commands like "airflow dbinit", stop/start web-server and scheduler etc...
- Install new python packages like "pip install "
- View and edit Airflow files in ECS cluster

I was reading about AWS CLI and ECS cli could they be helpful ? or is there is any other best possible way that lets me do above mentioned actions.

Thanks in Advance.

Kind Regards
P.

Answer (score 0):

There are many articles that describe how to run Airflow on ECS:

- https://tech.gc.com/apache-airflow-on-aws-ecs/
- https://towardsdatascience.com/building-an-etl-pipeline-with-airflow-and-ecs-4f68b7aa3b5b
- https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/running-airflow-on-aws-fargate/
- many more

[ Note: Fargate allows you to run containers via ECS without a need to have EC2 instances. More [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/the-role-of-aws-fargate-in-the-container-world/) if you want additional background re what Fargate is]

Also, AWS CLI is a generic CLI that maps all AWS APIs (mostly 1:1). You may consider it for your deployment (but it should not be your starting point).

The ECS CLI is a more abstracted CLI that exposes higher level constructs and workflows that are specific to ECS. Note that the ECS CLI has been superseded by [AWS Copilot](https://aws.github.io/copilot-cli/) which is an opinionated CLI to deploy workloads patterns on ECS. It's perhaps too opinionated to be able to deploy Airflow.

My suggestion is to go through the blogs above and get inspired.